# How to run the SAPUI5 sample apps - index.js is missing

Tags: sapui5

I would like to test different UI5 Sample apps (I was trying to run them in plunker), however the index.html file for every sample app I have downloaded requires `index.js` - however this JS file is not part of the zip.

If I remove the reference to `index.js`, but the App won't run - there is obviously some `init` code missing, which I am assuming is inside the missing `index.js` file.

Here is the basic [Page Sample](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Page/sample/sap.m.sample.Page/code) (click the download link in the top right to get the zip).

Here's what happens when I [move all the files to Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/kypjTTx48F6N6pG2XO8Q/) as-is.

You'll notice on line 20 of `index.html`, it is trying to include `index.js`, but this file isn't found, thus there is a 404 error in the console.

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/851bde42e4e1410c96abbe402fa9128c.html think these go through setting up the index.js ?

Comment: I downloaded the sample from your provided link but the index.html looks different to the one on Plunker. The downloaded index.html doesn't require an index.js. Apart from that, here is a link to the Walkthrough part with an index.js [Walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/4cfa60872dca462cb87148ccd0d948ee)